# Leaderboard polishing discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

its me again. I pretty much have a working leaderboard command, but it doesnt look nice. Is there anyone who could help me polishing my leaderboard?

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["level"], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> mit {top_users[user]}\n'

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Rangliste")
    embed.add_field(name="Spieler", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[This is how my leaderboard looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3sG9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["level"], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        names += f"{postion+1} - <@!{user}> mit Level: {top_users[user]['level']} Exp: {top_users[user]['xp']}\n"

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Rangliste")
    embed.add_field(name="Spieler", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```